# Euler's Formula explanation in $e^{ix} ⋅e^{iy}$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

According to Euler's Formula, $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x).$ 
I'm computing the product $e^{ix} \cdot e^{iy}.$

What is the real part (that is, the term without a factor of $i$)?

Why is it $\cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)??$

Comment: kingw3 yeah! an error...writing with the real part of the formula, why the conclusion to a minus sinxsiny??

Answer (score 2):

Use Euler's formula
$$e^{ix}e^{iy} = (\cos(x) + i \sin(x))(\cos(y) + i \sin(y))$$
then expand:
$$e^{ix}e^{iy} = \underbrace{(\cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y))}_{\text{real part}} + i\underbrace{(\cos(x)\sin(y) + \sin(x)\cos(y))}_{\text{imaginary part}}$$
So as @kingW3 comments, the real part is not $\sin(x)\cos(y) - \cos(x)\sin(y)??$, instead it should be $\cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)$.

Answer (score 2):

It is not. You get the formula wrong. The real part is $\cos x\cos y-\sin x \sin y$. This comes from $$\begin{align}e^{ix}e^{iy}&=(\cos x+i\sin x)(\cos y+i\sin y)\\&=\cos x\cos y+i\cos x \sin y+i\sin x\cos y+i^2\sin x\sin y\end{align}$$ Now using $i^2=-1$, you get $$e^{ix}e^{iy}=(\cos x\cos y-\sin x\sin y)+i(\sin x\cos y+\cos x\sin y)$$

Comment: i can see clearly!!!

Comment: Alternatively $e^{ix}e^{iy}=e^{i(x+y)}=\cos(x+y)+i\sin(x+y)$. You can then use trigonometric identities